# How to dynamically change href of edit path using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Bookings show page that with a next button that uses ajax to click through all a users' Bookings and replaces each instances' attributes. However, I need a way to dynamically change each edit and cancel path for each Bookings' show page.

```
<p class="userName" data-id="<%=@user.id%>"><%= "#{@user.name}'s 
Scheduled booking" %></p>
<a href="#" class="js-next" data-userid="<%=@user.id%>"data-id="<%= 
@booking.id %>">Next...</a>
<p class="lessonName"><%= @booking.lesson.name %></p>
<ul>
<li data-id="<%=@booking.id%>" id="bookingNote"><%= link_to "Manage 
notes", edit_user_booking_path(@user, @booking) %></li>
<li data-id="<%=@booking.id%>" id="cancelBooking"><%= link_to "Cancel 
Reservation", delete_booking_path(@booking) %></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function () {
$(".js-next").on("click", function() {
var userID = parseInt($(".js-next").attr("data-userid"));
var nextID = parseInt($(".js-next").attr("data-id")) + 1;
$.get("/users/" + userID + "/bookings/" + nextID + ".json", 
function(data) {
  $(".lessonName").text(data["lesson"]["name"]);
  $(".js-next").attr("data-id", data["id"]);
  });
 });
});
</script>
```

I need the href attribute in each booking edit and cancel routes for the current show path.

Comment: are you looking for a Jquery way to do it ? or it's the back parts that's hurt ?

Comment: I'm looking for a Jquery way to do it.

Comment: This seems like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) to me. I would be tempted to render a new list (or collection of list items) and replace the current list with the new list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) (after getting your new urls by ajax call)

```
$("#bookingNote a").prop("href", "Your New bookingNote link URL");
$("#cancelBooking a").prop("href", "Your New cancelBooking link URL");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use .attr()

```
$("a").attr("href", "http://www.google.com/")
```